# HTML5 accessibility/ARIA: What role should I use within an article for the translation?

Tags: html, translation, accessibility, wai-aria

I would like to improve the accessibility in a blog I'm working on. The blog is bilingual, and by default appears in Hungarian. A click on a flag triggers the language change (JavaScript removes `nodisplay` class from divs with `class=js-en` and adds it to divs with `class=js-hu`).

I would like to separate the two parts of each article. I have considered using `<aside>`, but it wouldn't be accurate (when viewed in English, it is also primary blog content).

What do you suggest to improve the accessibility, with valid tags and ARIA roles?

Posts look something like this:
[Edit: changed `<div class="js-en nodisplay">` to `<div class="js-en" hidden>`]

```html
<article>
  
  <div class="js-hu"> <!-- blog post in Hungarian -->
    <p>
      magyar szöveg, nem értenéd
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="js-en" hidden> <!-- blog post in English -->
    <p>
      same text in English
    </p>
  </div>
  
 </article>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isn't that more the role of the [lang](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Attributs_globaux/lang) attribute?

On the plus side you will be able to style the content depending on the language using the [`:lang` pseudo-class](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#lang).

Comment: Hm, I didn't think about that. It might be just what I'm looking for. `:lang` will be useful too. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

While the lang attribute is an important part of the communication, it does not represent an answer to your question.

For communicating the change for accessibility, you would use a WAI-ARIA *state*, not a *role*. In this case, the state to change on each element is the [`aria-hidden`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-hidden) attribute.

But, using the html `hidden` attribute does that for you. According to the W3C's [ARIA in HTML](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/#attr-hidden) draft spec, the aria-hidden state automatically reflects the `hidden` attribute. So as you're already using the hidden attribute, no further changes are necessary.

Comment: `lang` attribute is the perfect answer to the question *"What do you suggest to improve the accessibility?"*. Indisputably. You won't communicate the change of language by relying solely on the `hidden` attribute.

Comment: @Adam - true, which is why I said that the lang attribute was important. But setting the hidden attribute communicates the *change*, which guides the AT to tell the user the newly visible text.